Best way to aggregate an iterable of `polars.DataFrame` or `polars.Series` objects
I am looking for the best way to compute a per-row running sum (average) over a large number of polars.DataFrames, where each of the frames can potentially have a large number of rows. I'd like the implementation to be efficient (fast) but I want to keep the memory footprint in check, e.g. never assemble all the frames in memory before doing the aggregation.
This is my first attempt, but I am not sure if it's the best way to approach this problem.
import functools
import numpy as np
import polars as pl
from collections.abc import Iterable


def yields_frames(n: int = 100, nrows: int = 1_000_000, rng: np.random.Generator = np.random.default_rng()) -> Iterable[pl.DataFrame]:
    schema = ["A", "B", "C"]
    ncols = len(schema)
    for _ in range(n):
        data = rng.normal(size=(nrows, ncols))
        yield pl.from_numpy(data=data, schema=schema)


def running_sum(left: pl.DataFrame, right: pl.DataFrame) -> pl.DataFrame:
    assert left.schema == right.schema
    series = ((x + y) for x, y in zip(left.iter_columns(), right.iter_columns(), strict=True))
    return pl.DataFrame(series)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = functools.reduce(running_sum, yields_frames())
    print(result)

If left and right have identical schema, i.e. column names and types, can I always rely on iter_columns to yield individual columns in identical order? If not, how can I ensure this?
I was wondering if things could be further improved by using LazyFrames?
Would be glad to receive suggestions and ideas.

If the dataframes share a schema, even sum(yields_frames()) should work.

Neat, I wasn't aware that __add__ is overloaded for polars.DataFrame.
